# How can I determine the lengths of each side in a contour?

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I am using Python-OpenCV to detect shapes, measure their distance from the camera lens, and eventually measure the angle of the rotation of the shapes with respect to the camera.

[This is what it looks like when the shapes are parallel to the camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1csty.jpg)

[This is what it looks like when the shapes are slightly tilted/rotated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ak4kE.jpg)

I am trying to determine the angle of rotation of the board on which the shapes are placed, which is why I came up with the idea of comparing the lengths of the parallel sides of the rectangle to each other (any other Idea or tip is greatly appreciated).
[Required Lengths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10NYR.png)

The idea is that when the board is rotated, the parallel sides are no longer of equal length and I might be able to come up with a relation between the difference in length and the angle of rotation. I am open to any other suggestions.

I am struggling with calculating those lengths as shown in the picture above. I am trying to avoid using Hough Lines, and stick to Contours, since they proved to be a bit unstable in a live video.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: if the rectangular shape is parallel to the image planr, the sides will not intersect in a vanishing point

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/how-can-i-determine-the-lengths-of-each-side-in-a-contour/4558

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will give you the 4 corners.

```
p = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True) # cnt is the rect Contours
appr = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.02*p, True) # appr contains the 4 points

appr = sorted(appr, key=lambda c: c[0][0])

#pa = top lef point
#pb = bottom left point
#pc = top right point
#pd = bottom right point

pa, pb = sorted(appr[:2], key=lambda c: c[0][1])
pc, pd = sorted(appr[2:], key=lambda c: c[0][1])

# the points are x, y in list of list [[x, y]]
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I see those points? As in, (x1, y1) (x2, y2) (x3, y3) (x4, y4). If i can get the coordinates of each point then i can subtract them to get the length.

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot. Is there a way to separate the x's and y's? Lets say points "a" and "c" are the top left and top right corners of the rectangle, I want to be able to subtract the x-values to get the length of "ac". I am new to python so please don't judge my amateur questions :p . Thank you again!  @Ari

Comment: For each point `x = pa[0][0]` and `y = pa[0][1]`.

Comment: How can I do the same for a rectangle? What would i have to change in the above code for it to work? Thanks in advance. @Ari